# How to display a tree by level in C++

Tags: c++, tree

I'm trying display a tree level by level but it seems like I'm having trouble understanding the concept.  I know that I need to use a queue to push the different values in and then pop them later on.  The part that is confusing me the most is trying to determine when I need to include a new line.  Here's the most of the code.

Also each node has a Character, a Count, and left and right pointer.

```
//CharacterAnalyzer.cpp
string CharacterAnalyzer::displayByLevel(nodeptr_t const node, Function visit) const {
/* TODO (2):
 * Display the tree one level at a time. For each level
 * you must display all the nodes at that level.
 * 
 * If a child is absent (i.e. nullptr), then output 'null'.
 * 
 * So, for the text "Hello all!" the level display will be:
 * (H,1)
 * (E,1)(L,4)
 * (A,1)(null)(null)(O,1)
 * (null)(null)(null)(null)
 */

}// end displayByLevel()
```

I'm assuming this is used for the Function visit in the parameter.  This is the the CharacterAnalyzer.h

```
// using Function = string (const char character, const int count) *;
typedef string (* Function)(const char character, const int count);
```

Here's one method I tried that failed

```
string str = "";

if (node == nullptr) {
    return str += "(null)";
}  

queue<nodeptr_t> q;  

q.push(node);  

while (q.empty() == false)  
{  
    // nodeCount (queue size) indicates number 
    // of nodes at current level.  
    int nodeCount = q.size();  

    while (nodeCount > 0) 
    {  
        nodeptr_t node = q.front();  
        str += visit(node->character, node->count) + " ";  
        q.pop();  
        if (node->left != nullptr)  
            q.push(node->left);  
        if (node->right != nullptr)  
            q.push(node->right);  
        nodeCount--;  
    }  
    str += "";  
}
```

Comment: Tree by level sounds an awful lot like you want a (incoming search term!) breadth-first traversal.

Comment: We just talked about this in class recently!  That's most likely what I want to do but what would be the best way to initiate the new lines?

Comment: If you know the tree is full (except for the bottom level) have a current level counter as well as a nodes-on-current-line counter and when you reach pow(2, level) on the current line output a newline. It's a lot trickier if you have to deal with truly arbitrary trees.